Not able to launch electron application with arguments using selenium chrome webdriver
I have an electron application, which launches with port 9555,
e.g.application.exe 9555
Since ChromeDriver does not accept anything beyond exe, how do I set this port for initializing webdriver to create session and perform actions on it.
I have already tried.
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setBinary("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\application.exe");
options.addArguments("9555");


Might check here: https://www.electronjs.org/pt/docs/latest/tutorial/using-selenium-and-webdriver  (I think you might have to build it in to your app?  That may be why it's showing JS code there?)
